# Не работает функция 'in' проверки наличия элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript

Плохо работает функция 'in' проверки наличия элемента в массиве или просто глаз замылился.

```
arr1 = new Array();
arr1[0] = 1;
arr1[1] = 2;
arr1[2] = 3;

arr2 = new Array();
arr2[0] = 3;
arr2[1] = 4;

for ( var key in arr2 ) {
    // for ( var key=0; key < arr2.lenght; key++ ) {
    // DONT WORK.. javascript is BROKEN?))
    if (arr2[key] in arr1 )
        alert('Yes!');
    else
        alert('No!');   // почему?
}
```

Гляньте примерчик: https://jsfiddle.net/nywuctuk/pwk2ppx7/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in оператор возвращает true, если у объекта есть данное свойство. Массив - это тоже объект в JavaScript, но его свойства это индексы, а не сами значения из массива. Вот так будет работать:

```
if (key in arr1) {
  alert('Yes!');
}
```

Если хотите проверить есть ли данный элемент в массиве:

```
if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[key]) != -1) {
  alert('Yes!');
}
```

Comment: спасибо! не подскажете каким мануальчиком лучше пользоваться по Js..

Comment: Англоязычный и полный -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript, на русском -- http://javascript.ru/

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, то отметьте галочкой, а если нет, то напишите, что конкретно не работает :)

Comment: @SergeiStralenia, по русскоязычному, лучше новую версию его сайта - https://learn.javascript.ru/